# Why is it possible in Python to have an except clause for an undefined exception?

Tags: python

My google-fu is failing me. Why does the following program compile and run with no error (Python 2 and 3)?

```
try:
    print('something')
except ThisNameDoesNotExist:
    print('blah')
```

I can't think of a good reason why this wouldn't cause an error. I get that it's not executing that except clause, so not hitting the undefined variable, but it seems like it should be fairly easy to catch to me. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: You basically answered your own question.  In general, Python doesn't try to evaluate anything until and unless the line of code where it is evaluated is actually executed.  Since no exception is raised, the except line is never reached, so the undefined name is not evaluated.

Comment: In addition to what @BrenBarn said, the interpreter would only parse the input for syntax to begin with.

Comment: You can also do `except 4` or `except exception_raising_function()`. Python can't check whether the name exists until you hit the `except` block, because the name might not be in any of the namespaces in the name resolution chain until you execute an `import` or a class definition or something.

Comment: In addition to the comments: using any acceptable IDE or just a text editor with a linter, it will warn you about not defined variables (in your case, the exception).

Comment: user2357112: best answer I think, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You **do** get the error if Python actually evaluates that line. As soon as there is an exception, it sees `ThisNameDoesNotExist` does not exist:

```
>>> try:
...     print(1/0)
... except ThisNameDoesNotExist:
...     print('blah')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'ThisNameDoesNotExist' is not defined
```

Otherwise, there is no error, as is the nature of the Python.